# .NET RegEx to remove lines that end in .PDF

Tags: .net, regex, nintex-workflow

I'm pulling in a mix of URLs that link back to different file types. I want to use RegEx to remove the URLs that match `.pdf`, however I'm not sure how to do this without affecting the `.html`, `.ppt` `.doc` URL's.

```
http://www.myurl.com/library/mydocument.doc
http://www.myurl.com/library/somefile.pdf
```

I tried different examples posted on here, but they were for Java and C# so they did not work.

Thanks for the help

Edits

I'm using Nintex RegEx which is based on .NET from what I've read. I have absolutely no experience with C#, Java, .NET etc...

I'm currently pulling the library URLs from SharePoint which contains different file type endings. I was able to figure out how to remove the unwanted file types, however it is still causing a problem for me.

This is my following layout

```
pattern = `.*pdf.*|.*pptx.*|`

Replacement =
```

The problem is I get CRLF for the empty lines. I then tried the following below

```
pattern = `.*pdf.*|.*pptx.*|[\r\n]*`
Replacement =
```

The problem is once I add the remove CRLF it places all the strings into one line.

Comment: `They were for C# so they did not work.`... you realize that C# is on the .NET platform, right?

Comment: `\.pdf$` will match lines ending in `.pdf` you can then select all the lines which do not match this to filter them out.

Answer (score 2):

When filtering out file extensions in .NET you can use [Path.GetExtension](http://www.dotnetperls.com/path-getextension).

Example:

```
using System.IO;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] files = new string[3]
        {
            "http://www.myurl.com/library/mydocument.doc",
            @"C:\files\somefile.pdf",
            "someotherfile.pdf",
        };

        List<string> filteredFiles = new List<string>(); 
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(file) != ".pdf")
            {
                filteredFiles.Add(file);
                Console.WriteLine(file);
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add this Linq to your answer as an alternative `var filteredFiles = files.Where (name => Path.GetExtension(name) != ".pdf").ToList();` which does the same as your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will only work with http(s) which ultimately end in pdfs and possible whitespace..

```
string data = @"alphapdf
http://www.myurl.com/library/mydocument.doc
http://www.myurl.com/library/somefile.pdf
Gamma";

string pattern = @"http.+?\.pdf[\s\r\n]*";
```

By including the whitespace of spaces and CRLFs to be matched, using `.Net` Regex.Replace will remove the whole line.

```
Regex.Replace(data, pattern, string.Empty)
```

Result:

```
alphapdf
http://www.myurl.com/library/mydocument.doc
Gamma
```